# Set borders for an expanded group item using ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, material-design

I'm trying to find a way of creating a material-styled `ExpandableListView`, and I'm using the example located at the [material design website](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists-controls.html#lists-controls-types-of-list-controls). The example I'm following is:

[image: Material Design Expandable List View]

I'm trying to replicate the borders that appear at the top and bottom of the group when the group is expanded, but I don't know where to start.

Can you help?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution?